# I switched from Windows to Linux mint, and now only 2 of my 6 rams are working

Tags: memory, linux-mint

I googled a lot, but I found no one who had the same problem as me.

Here some informations

```
uname -a:
Linux pauls-rechner 4.8.0-53-generic #56~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 16 01:18:56 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

dmidecode -t memory:

*-memory                                                                                                                                                   
       Beschreibung: Systemspeicher                                                                                                                          
       Physische ID: 24                                                                                                                                      
       Steckplatz: Systemplatine oder Hauptplatine                                                                                                           
       Größe: 4GiB                                                                                                                                           
     *-bank:0                                                                                                                                                
          Beschreibung: DIMM DDR2 Synchron 1066 MHz (0,9 ns) [leer]                                                                                          
          Physische ID: 0                                                                                                                                    
          Steckplatz: DIMM-CHA0 CPU0                                                                                                                         
          Takt: 1066MHz (0.9ns)                                                                                                                              
     *-bank:1                                                                                                                                                
          Beschreibung: DIMM DDR2 Synchron 1066 MHz (0,9 ns) [leer]                                                                                          
          Physische ID: 1                                                                                                                                    
          Steckplatz: DIMM-CHA1 CPU0                                                                                                                         
          Takt: 1066MHz (0.9ns)                                                                                                                              
     *-bank:2                                                                                                                                                
          Beschreibung: DIMM DDR2 Synchron 1066 MHz (0,9 ns)                                                                                                 
          Produkt: M391B5673EH1-CH9
          Hersteller: Samsung
          Physische ID: 2
          Seriennummer: 86C71EA6
          Steckplatz: DIMM-CHB0 CPU0
          Größe: 2GiB
          Breite: 64 bits
          Takt: 1066MHz (0.9ns)
     *-bank:3
          Beschreibung: DIMM DDR2 Synchron 1066 MHz (0,9 ns) [leer]
          Physische ID: 3
          Steckplatz: DIMM-CHB1 CPU0
          Takt: 1066MHz (0.9ns)
     *-bank:4
          Beschreibung: DIMM DDR2 Synchron 1066 MHz (0,9 ns)
          Produkt: M391B5673EH1-CH9
          Hersteller: Samsung
          Physische ID: 4
          Seriennummer: 83294189
          Steckplatz: DIMM-CHC0 CPU0
          Größe: 2GiB
          Breite: 64 bits
          Takt: 1066MHz (0.9ns)
     *-bank:5
          Beschreibung: DIMM DDR2 Synchron 1066 MHz (0,9 ns) [leer]
          Physische ID: 5
          Steckplatz: DIMM-CHC1 CPU0
          Takt: 1066MHz (0.9ns)
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: 32- or 64-bit version of Mint? 32-bit may not be able to access all RAM.

Comment: Does Linux Mint really don't see the RAM or is it just missing in `dmidecode`? Did you check the output of `free` and the content of `/proc/meminfo`? And please add the relevant kernel bootup log output from `dmesg`. Another thing you can try to boot another Linux distribution from an USB stick (or DVD) like Ubuntu or Knoppix and check if you get the same problem. This could help to track down the root cause of the error.